# React server side rendering - preloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, preloading

I am wondering how to resolve a preloading of components based on user's location. For example: he is on home page and there are 5 links to another pages (like Products listing, Login, Register etc) and I am trying to preload these pages (download from server) for best (fastest) user experience - so user doesn't have to wait for pages to download.

Let's say I have already resolved the code splitting. How would you analyze a page for Links (react-router) and preload those relevant components?

I use React 16 with Nodejs (Express)

btw. I would be very happy for typescript specific use case